# Firebase Functions stopped Working and Can't deploy again

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Cloud functions giving an error called.

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

When I try to re-deploy, it gives following error.

```
Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try again after a few minutes.
```

What could be the reason? Is it following issue?
Sates: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18018

Comment: Same issue here:  ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try again after a few minutes.      I'm on ca-central-1

Comment: try to deploy now. I just redeployed my functions and it worked just takes a bit of minutes

Comment: Yeah. It's working now. Thanks everyone <3

Comment: If you have obvious and unexpected errors coming from Firebase products, you should contact Firebase support. firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @PeterHaddad Sorry dear, I forgot. ;) 
much love. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is an issue with Cloud Functions, as you can see from the link above

> Investigating an issue with Functions
>
> Incident began at 2018-03-09 03:30 (all times are US/Pacific).

Last update is this:

> Mar 09, 2018    04:45
> We are still investigating the issue with Cloud Functions execution. We will provide another status update as soon as possible.

https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18018

After the issue is done, you will be able to deploy your functions again using the below:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Edit:

I just deployed some functions and it is working now, just takes a bit of time.

Comment: I too have had the same issue.  Updating my npm, switching to another project and back seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was fixed after updating firebase-tools. I saw following on my console

```
         Update available 7.0.0 → 7.8.1       
         Run npm i -g firebase-tools to update
```

Then i just changed node version and updated firebase tools

```
nvm use 11
npm upgrade firebase-tools -g
```

Sometimes switching environment will also help

```
firebase use dev
```

Sometimes when some node modules are not installed , the error you get will be like below

```
Deployment error.
Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes.
```

**Make sure that all node modules are installed prior to deployment, I wasted almost 2 days and realised one node module was not installed .**

Comment: Not having all modules installed was the problem for me too. This is particularly tricky if you work with a monorepo using workspaces. Because your the editor / linting tool might not indicate that the module can't be found. I moved some code from one package to my cloud functions package. The modules were still found but not part of my cloud functions package.json.

Comment: What modules? I upgraded recently from angular 7 to 8 and i had many problems that i was able to solve, but this one does not want to go away.

Comment: @Gigalala I cant remember , that was some module related to pdf export

Answer (score 1):

I tried several different steps, including updating tools from firebase, using different node versions or dependencies on `package.json`. In the end, at firebase functions console, I cleared the log stack and tried to reach every deployment notification after executing `firebase deploy`. I found out one of my dependencies were moved from `dependencies` to `devDependencies`, which was causing

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try again after a few minutes.`

[image]

Solution:

1. Place back dependency on its place, moving from `devDependencies` into `dependencies` itself.
2. Update project dependencies with `npm install`
3. Re-deploy with `firebase deploy`